# top navigation disappear in modern page when active feature “sharepoint server publishing infrastructure”

Tags: sharepoint-online

My top navigation in Modern Sharepoint site is disappear when i enable feature “sharepoint server publishing infrastructure”, it’s just show when i edit link, but it disappear again when i refresh page or click this.
how can i fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my SharePoint online and I cannot reproduce your issue.

Top navigation will not disappear in modern page when active feature “sharepoint server publishing infrastructure”.

What is the template of your site?

Try to create a new modern page and compare the results.

Do all users cannot see the Top navigation when active feature “sharepoint server publishing infrastructure”?